# How to insert a "\" in mySql

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have This code to Load a Image and to get the image path and to save in into the database .. btnBrowse_click

But after inserting the image path in database .. the "\" is missing . it is not save in database . The code is below

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.IO
Imports Microsoft.Win32
Public Class frmAddParty
    Public sConnection As New MySqlConnection


    Private Sub btnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
        If sConnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            sConnection.ConnectionString = "SERVER = localhost; USERID = root; PASSWORD=; DATABASE = db_VSDatabase"
            sConnection.Open()

            Dim sqlQuery As String = "INSERT INTO tbl_party (party, description, info, logo) VALUES('" & txtParty.Text _
                                     & "','" & txtDes.Text & "', '" & txtInfo.Text & "', '" & txtPath.Text & "')"


            Dim sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand
            With sqlCommand
                .CommandText = sqlQuery
                .Connection = sConnection
                .ExecuteNonQuery()
            End With

            MessageBox.Show("Party List Created", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            Dispose()
            Close()
            frmLogin.Show()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub frmAddParty_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        txtId.Enabled = False

    End Sub


    Private Sub btnMenu_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnMenu.Click
        frmAdminMenu.Show()
        Me.Hide()

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnBrowse_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnTry.Click
        Dim img As String
        Dim myStream As Stream = Nothing
        Dim openFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog()

        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "d:\"
        openFileDialog1.Filter = Nothing
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2
        openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True
        openFileDialog1.FileName = ""

        If openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            Try
                myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()
                If (myStream IsNot Nothing) Then
                    txtPath.Text = ""

                    img = openFileDialog1.FileName
                    pctLogo.Image = System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile(img)

                    txtPath.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("Cannot Read file from disk." & ex.Message)
            Finally
                If (myStream IsNot Nothing) Then
                    myStream.Close()
                End If
            End Try

        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Use "\\". .....

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection. Use parameterized queries. Actually doing so could _potentially_ solve your problem as well.

Comment: i cant use a parametized query because is a voting system . image is needed . and registration of candidate is required to have a image .. the user will select hi/her image .. is there any other solution ?

Comment: Why would that stop you from using a parameterized query? You are inputting text.

Comment: Right now they could just enter something like: `'); DROP TABLE tbl_party; -- ` into the last text box and your data is gone.

Comment: Always use SQL Parameters.  This is just one of the things it prevents, another is the hard to read, hard to write code to build the SQL

Comment: Problem solve sir .. 
 `Dim doubleSlash As String = Chr(92) & Chr(92)
     txtPath.Text = txtPath.Text.Replace("\", doubleSlash)`

Comment: @LhenardCabajar That is **NOT** a good solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This will fix the problem. Additionally, it should run faster, be easier to maintain, and also solve the **massive** sql injection vulnerability in the current code:

```
Private ConnectionString As String = "SERVER = localhost; USERID = root; PASSWORD=; DATABASE = db_VSDatabase"

Private Sub btnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click

    Dim sqlQuery As String = "INSERT INTO tbl_party (party, description, info, logo) VALUES(@party, @description, @info, @logo)"

    Using cn  As New MySqlConnection(ConnectionString), _
          cmd As New MySqlCommand(sqlQuery, cn)

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@party", VarString).Value = txtParty.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@description", VarString).Value = txtDes.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@info",VarString).Value = txtInfo.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@logo", VarString).Value = txtPath.Text

        sConnection.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using

    MessageBox.Show("Party List Created", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    frmLogin.Show()
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

```
If openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            Dim doubleSlash As String = Chr(92) & Chr(92)

            Try
                myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()
                If (myStream IsNot Nothing) Then
                    txtPath.Text = ""

                    img = openFileDialog1.FileName
                    pctLogo.Image = System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile(img)

                    txtPath.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName
                    txtPath.Text = txtPath.Text.Replace("\", doubleSlash)
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("Cannot Read file from disk." & ex.Message)
            Finally
                If (myStream IsNot Nothing) Then
                    myStream.Close()
                End If
            End Try


        End If
```

I replace the single backslash into "\"

Comment: This code is still crazy vulnerable to sql injection attacks. It's practically begging to get hacked.

Comment: Just use parameters! It is indeed possible and there's nothing stopping you from doing so - all you're ever inputting is text! (even the image, as it's just a path pointing to a file)